# Using a wildcard with a cell reference. What am I missing?

Tags: vba, excel

In Sheet A are a list of names.  I am attempting to count the different names on Sheet A in a table on Sheet B, Column B.  The names are not exact and I will be referring to the cell and not writing in the name.  The sub below almost works but I think I am not using the wildcqard correctly.  Please help if you can.  thanks in advance.

```
Sub Countif_Crr_Cnt_Until_LastRow()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim wb1 As Workbook


    Set wb1 = Workbooks("macro all client v.01.xlsm")

    LastRow = wb1.Sheets("A").Range("A:A").Find("Overall - Total", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = 21 To LastRow

Cells(i, 10) = Application.CountIfs(wb1.Sheets("B").Range("B:B"), "*" & Cells(i, 3) & "*")

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Which sheet do you expect `Cells(i,10)` to be on? Same with `Cells(i,3)`?  I believe that's the issue that's not working. You are using the wildcard correctly, but as you have multiple sheets being referenced, you have to add the specific sheet to your `Cells()` use as well.

Comment: try putting `wb1.Sheets("A").` in front of both `Cells(...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is the unqualified references when you use just `Cells()`.  VBA needs to know what sheet you expect that to be on, when using multiple sheets.  I'm assuming that the `Cells(i,10)` and `Cells(i,3)` are to be on Sheet "A". If not, just change the sheet name:

`wb1.Sheets("A").Cells(i, 10) = Application.CountIfs(wb1.Sheets("B").Range("B:B"), "*" & wb1.Sheets("A").Cells(i, 3) & "*")`

As you can see, that's kind of long and a little tricky to read. An alternative way of doing that, is use `With`:

```
With wb1.Sheets("A")
   .Cells(i,10) = Application.CountIfs(wb1.Sheets("B").Range("B:B"), "*" & .Cells(i,3) & "*")
End With
```

So, wherever you see a simple `.Cells()` without anything before the `.`, it's going to use what follows `With`.  So it's the equivalent of the formula above...does that make sense?

Comment: I understand that, but if I search the name "Basic Term Life" in cell C21 of Sheet A in the table on Sheet B  and Sheet B's names are not exact "Basic Life Insurance" my macro does not count the names that arent exact.  How can I update the wildcard references to count all similar names?

Comment: @t.mo - Maybe add some if statements, where if it doesn't find with `*Basic Term*`, then search for something more specific?  How many ways can your data given?